# Does using pushstate with content repeat cause SEO issues?

Tags: javascript, html, seo

I am aware there are several other similar types of questions about pushState and SEO, but I cannot find one asking about this issue.

If I have a page with url site.com/Product/Detail2, that loads all the "pages" associated with site.com/Product into it and then scrolls Detail2 into view, will it cause problems with SEO if there are links like site.com/Product/Detail1 and site.com/Product/Detail3?  Each of these urls will actually load the same exact content, but scroll the user to the portion of the page that detail is on similar to how fragment identifiers work.  I understand Google wont run the JavaScript and will spider all those product urls, but I have read that google doesn't like different urls returning the exact same content.  For example, site.com/Product/Detail1 and site.com/Product/Detail2 will both return the same content when user initial navigates to them, and code will scroll the user to the specific detail.

I don't want to have to do ajax calls to dynamically load content to avoid the different product sub urls from pulling up the exact same content.  I could see a solution where navigating to each url initial loads only that one sub url's content but then gets the rest of the Product content with ajax calls.  That would allow google to think each of those product urls returns unique content but the users always sees one big page that scrolls the sub urls into view when they use the nav bar.

Has anyone else thought about this specific issue and dealt with it before?

Comment: i don't think you will be penalized for repetitive content, so long as that's not all you have

Answer (score 0):

Use the `canonical` tag on the detail pages (ones that describe only one item and ideally have descriptive urls).

[More on rel="canonical"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Comment: This does appear to be the answer needed.  I wasn't really aware of that canonical link option.  I hope that google and other search engines truly honor that if the content really is identical.  Maybe there are gotchas such as they test the various sub urls such as Product/Detail1 and Product/Detail2 are returning the same content but because you've got server side rotating content (such as ads) the content actually isn't EXACTLY the same.

Comment: I think they have to, at this point. A lot of stes these days load content from multiple "pages" at once, not to mention RSS feeds and all sorts of mashups. My experience with using this tag has definitely been positive, and I think it's one of those rare cases where it can't be directly abused by black hatters, because as soon as you put it on more than one page, it automatically becomes invalid. Good luck with your site.

Comment: One issue I see with using canonical is that it also indicates the preferred url for the url the browser is actually on.  That seems to be an issue.  I want site.com/Product/Detail2 to be the preferred url for someone wanting to go directly to Detail2.  I dont want them using site.com/Product for all the sub urls such as site.com/Product/Detail1 and site.com/Product/Detail2.

Comment: It seems for guaranteed results and probably a good fallback for older browsers is to have sub urls such as site.com/Product/Detail2 initially load with only the Detail2 portion of the overall Product content, then using javascript load all the other Detail[N] portions that make up the overall Product.  That way search engines will properly index site.com/Product/Detail2 as the url for content that is in that portion of the overall content.  Users still get the same feeling of one long page that scrolls around to content.  Seems the best possible solution, though more complex.